# Multiple input to one output

Tags: javascript, algorithm

How can i handle multiple input values to one output value?

```
function c(input,val){
    return input.indexOf(val)>-1;   
}

function result(i){
    if(c(i,1) && c(i,2) && c(i,3)){
       return "alpha";
    }else if(c(i,1) && c(i,2) && !c(i,3)){ 
       return "beta";
    }else if(c(i,1) && !c(i,2) && c(i,3)){
       return "gamma";
    }else if(c(i,1) && !c(i,2)){ 
       return "delta";
    }else if(c(i,3)){
       return "theta";
    }
   //..... and so on covering all possible combinations

   return null;
}

result([1,2,3]);     //output : alpha
result([1,3,2]);     //output : alpha
result([1,3,1,1]);   //output : gamma
result([1,2,4]);     //output : beta
result([3]);         //output : theta
```

Number of values in array can be N, but from a predefined set of values only

What is the right way to work with so many combinations?

Comment: `[1,3,1,1]` is not a valid combination of `[1,2,3]` unless your definition of "combination" is different from the commonly accepted definition.

Comment: A switch case would be less verbose. If it's static (always return the same output given a set of inputs) look into using a look-up type structure.

Comment: How many combinations are there in total?

Comment: @Codor Combinations are 100 as of now but may expand in future.

Comment: @RobG [1,3,1,1] is an input and not a valid combination, it has to be de-duped to [1,3] which is a valid combination, de-duping is not an issue so it was skipped.

Comment: It is an issue for those trying to give you an answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Condor's answer, the following should do the job. It uses a sequence of tests to work out the result and also implements the "not" tests. If a value is "true" it must appear, if a value is "false" it must not appear. If it isn't mentioned, it doesn't matter if it's in the values or not.

Duplicates aren't an issue, values are processed until one fails. Removing duplicates first might speed it up a bit though.

The result is the name of the first set of tests that pass.

```
function testValues(values) {

  var checks = [
      {alpha:  {1:true,  2:true,  3:true }},
      {beta :  {1:true,  2:true,  3:false}},
      {gamma:  {1:true,  2:false, 3:true }},
      {theta:  {3:true}}
  ];
  var check, resultName, tests, passed;

  // Do checks in sequence
  for (var i=0, iLen=checks.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    check = checks[i]

    // Get name of result to return if the checks pass
    for (resultName in check) {

      // Make sure result is own property
      if (check.hasOwnProperty(resultName)) {

        // Passed is true until a fail is found
        passed = true;

        // Get tests to perform
        tests = check[resultName];

        // For each value in tests, make sure value exists or doesn't in values
        for (var v in tests) {

          if (tests.hasOwnProperty(v)) {

            // Only test if passed is true
            if (passed) {

              // Note that indexOf uses === so must have same type
              // Property names are always strings so if passing numbers,
              // Must convert to numbers
              passed = tests[v] === (values.indexOf(+v) != -1);
            }
          }
        }

        // If passed tests, return
        if (passed) return resultName;

      }
    }
  }
  return 'failed all tests...';
}

console.log(testValues([1,2,3]));     //output : alpha
console.log(testValues([1,3,2]));     //output : alpha
console.log(testValues([1,3,1,1]));   //output : gamma
console.log(testValues([1,2,4]));     //output : beta
console.log(testValues([3]));         //output : theta
```

The code could be a bit shorter if *Object.keys* is used with *forEach*, but the above is  a bit clearer (perhaps), it can be refactored to be shorter. The above will work in ECMA-262 ed 3 environments if a shim for *Array.prototype.indexOf* is provided.

#### Edit

If modern features are used, the code can be simplified a bit. Providing support for older browsers isn't difficult:

```
// These are sufficient to support the function but are not suitable for general use
// Better versions are avaialble at MDN, see links below
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = function(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        keys.push(key);
      }
    }
    return keys;
  };
}

if (!Array.prototype.indeOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (value) {
    for (var i=0, iLen=this.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      if (this[i] === value) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}

function testValues(values) {

  var checks = [
      {alpha:  {1:true,  2:true,  3:true }},
      {beta :  {1:true,  2:true,  3:false}},
      {gamma:  {1:true,  2:false, 3:true }},
      {theta:  {3:true}}
  ];
  var check, passed, resultName, tests, testKeys;

  for (var i=0, iLen=checks.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    check = checks[i]
    resultName = Object.keys(check)[0];
    passed = true;
    tests = check[resultName];
    testKeys = Object.keys(tests);

    for (var j=0, jLen=testKeys.length; j<jLen && passed; j++) {
      passed = tests[testKeys[j]] === (values.indexOf(+testKeys[j]) != -1);
    }

    if (passed) return resultName;
  }
  return 'failed all tests...';
}
```

Object.keys: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Array.prototype.indexOf: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

The code could perhaps be organized more clearly if the cases are easier accessible. For instance, the `alpha` case could be formualted by an array `[1,2,3]` which would list the numbers on which the code depend and and array of boolean values `[true,true,true]` which would indicate whether the corresponding number occurs or not. The checking could be implemented with a function as follows.

```
function check_case(values,bools){
   var Result = true;
   for ( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ){
     Result = Result && ( c(values[i]) == bools[i] );
   }
   return Result;
}
```

This circumvents the formulation of conditions in which results of `c` have to be negated individually, which makes them difficult to follow and edit.

The idea could be taken a step further by having an array of cases which would also hold the names of the cases. An array containing the first two cases above would then be as follows.

```
[
  {
    values: [1,2,3],
    bools:  [true,true,true],
    name:   'alpha'
  },
  {
    values: [1,2,3],
    bools:  [true,true,false],
    name:   'beta'
  }
]
```

The code would then iterate over this array, calling `check_case` for every index and returning the value of `name` for the first hit.

Answer (score 0):

Let your predefined array be:- [3,2,1] (i am keeping this short for simplicity, this can extend to N elements)

predefined array as boolean string can be visualized as:- 123

You can treat this number as boolean and create your desired output mapping:-

Example:- If no number :- 000 0
If only 1 is present:- 100 4
If only 1 and 2 are present :- 110 6

and so on all the required boolean combinations can be defined

So for N numbers you can create a list of all the possible combinations you want

Example:- var definedSet = {"0":"Alpha","1":"beta","2":"gama","3":"x","4":"y","5":"z","6":"a","7":"b"};

Now take input and remove duplicates and check the location (bit location of the number and create a boolean value and map this to defined set)

Code:-

```
function sortAndRemoveDuplicates(arr) {
    arr.sort( function(a, b) { return a - b; } );
    var copy = arr.slice(0);
    arr.length = 0;

    for (var i = 0, len = copy.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i == 0 || copy[i] != copy[i - 1]) {
            arr.push(copy[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var definedArr = [3,2,1];
var definedSet = {"0":"Alpha","1":"beta","2":"gama","3":"x","4":"y","5":"z","6":"a","7":"b"};

var inputArr=[1,4,3,1,1];
sortAndRemoveDuplicates(inputArr);

var outBooleanValue = 0;
for(var i=0;i<inputArr.length;i++)
{
    var numIndex =definedArr.indexOf(inputArr[i]); 
    if(numIndex!=-1)
    {
        outBooleanValue+=Math.pow(2,numIndex);         
    }
}

result =definedSet[outBooleanValue.toString()];
alert(result);
```

Here is the working fiddle:-

### http://jsfiddle.net/9tFnn/1/

Here is another version of this where predefined inputs are not required and it allows you to give conditions as you specified:-

```
var definedSet = {"1":"alpha","12":"beta","12!3":"gama","123":"delta"};

$("#defined-set").html(JSON.stringify(definedSet));

var inputArr=[1,2];
$("#input").html(JSON.stringify(inputArr));
$.unique(inputArr);
inputArr.sort();
var outputStr = inputArr.join('');
var regexStr = '';
var loopCounter=0;
for(loopCounter=0;loopCounter<outputStr.length;loopCounter++)
    regexStr+='(!\\d)*'+outputStr[loopCounter]+'(!\\d)*';

regexStr+='$';

//var regexPattern = new RegExp(regexStr);

console.log(regexStr);

for(var currSet in definedSet)
{
     //var match = regexPattern.test(currSet);
    var match = currSet.search(regexStr);  
    if(match!=-1)
    {
         if(currSet==outputStr)
        {
            $("#result").append("Exact Match::");    
        }
        $("#result").append(currSet+"<br/>");
    }



}
```

Here is the link to working fiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/hLUuF/1/

Note:- This is just a basic prototype of the algorithm used to get to the answer, this can be modified according to the programming needs.

Hope this proves to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that the order of elements in the input is not important. That is, an input of `[1, 3, 2]` is the same as an input of `[1, 2, 3]`.

It looks like what you're trying to do is take a set of possible inputs from a range `(1..n)`, each of which may or may not be present. In other words, for a range of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, one possible input would be `[1, 3]`. Or,

```
Out of:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
We want: [x, 0, x, 0]
```

Which looks suspiciously like a binary number, especially if we reverse the order. So all we really need to do is

1. Convert our input to a binary number
2. Use that binary number as an index into a predefined look-up table of values

For the first part all we need to do is loop through the input values and `OR` the appropriate bits together. This also automatically takes care of any duplicates.

```
for (i=0;i<input_array.length;i++)
{
    num = num | (1 << (input_array[i] - 1));
}
```

The `- 1` in there is because our sequence starts from `1` rather than `0`. So an input of `4` will result in `1000` and an input of `2` will result in `0010`. `OR`-ing them together gives us `1010` or 10 (decimal).

Now num contains the index into our table which we set up beforehand:

```
values[0] = "alpha";   // Corresponding to input []
values[1] = "beta";    // Corresponding to input [1]
...
values[10] = "gamma";  // Corresponding to input [4, 2] - remember, it's reversed
...
values[15] = "theta";  // Corresponding to input [4, 3, 2, 1]
```